# NAs returned when extracting values from a raster

Tags: r, extract, raster

I am trying to extract values from a raster showing density of bears using a spatial points file my script is as follows:

```
## set the working directory                                                         
##

setwd("~/Masters/Research Project/R Scripts/Focal_Raster")

## install packages to use                                                           
##

library(raster)
library (rgdal)

## import the raster and the csv file that will be used in the habitat 
## location      ##
## extraction                                                                       

r <- raster("bear_12zero2.tif")
r
plot(r, main = "Bear Density")

hist(r[])
head(r[],200)

locations<-read.csv("PA_AllBears_1.csv")
plot(locations$X,locations$Y, main="BearID")

## first need to assign a coordinate reference system to the csv file of 
## data        ##
## locations that we want to extract                                                 

crs(locations)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
crs(r)

locationsC = SpatialPoints(cbind(locations$X, locations$Y), 
                       proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
cord.UTM <- spTransform(locationsC, crs(r))
cord.UTM


## Now we just need to extract the raster values from these locations                
##
TRI<-extract(r,cord.UTM,method='simple')

TRI

## need to write CSV file to join to the master datasheet with all varibles 
## in       ##

write.csv(TRI,'beardensity.csv')
```

When I run the script the the raster shows:

```
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2000, 1394, 2788000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 2248.04, 2248.04  (x, y)
extent      : -27831.02, 3105937, 4846432, 9342512  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
+towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\Kate\Documents\Masters\Research Project\R 
Scripts\Focal_Raster\bear_12zero2.tif 
names       : bear_12zero2
```

but when I try to extract values using the locations csv I have imported and transformed to the same projection I end up with all NAs. I have a similar error with another raster I am using which has the same projection and using the same extraction points.

My results are as follows:

```
> setwd("~/Masters/Research Project/R Scripts/Focal_Raster")
> library(raster)
> library (rgdal)
> r <- raster("bear_12zero2.tif")
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2000, 1394, 2788000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 2248.04, 2248.04  (x, y)
extent      : -27831.02, 3105937, 4846432, 9342512  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
+towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\Kate\Documents\Masters\Research Project\R 
Scripts\Focal_Raster\bear_12zero2.tif 
names       : bear_12zero2 

> plot(r, main = "Bear Density")
> locations<-read.csv("PA_AllBears_1.csv")
> plot(locations$X,locations$Y, main="BearID")
> summary(locations)
     BearID             X               Y              P_A     
 Min.   : 2.000   Min.   :18.37   Min.   :65.61   Min.   :0.0  
 1st Qu.: 5.000   1st Qu.:20.11   1st Qu.:66.34   1st Qu.:0.0  
 Median : 8.000   Median :21.09   Median :66.53   Median :0.5  
 Mean   : 8.273   Mean   :20.78   Mean   :66.51   Mean   :0.5  
 3rd Qu.:12.000   3rd Qu.:21.46   3rd Qu.:66.74   3rd Qu.:1.0  
 Max.   :15.000   Max.   :22.35   Max.   :67.08   Max.   :1.0  
> str(locations)
 'data.frame':  5500 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ BearID: int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ X     : num  19.5 19 18.8 19.4 19.7 ...
 $ Y     : num  66.4 66.1 66.2 66.3 66.2 ...
 $ P_A   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> crs(locations)
[1] NA
> library(rgdal)
> library(sp)
> crs(r)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
 +towgs84=0,0,0 
> locationsC = SpatialPoints(cbind(locations$X, locations$Y), 
+                            proj4string=CRS(("+init=epsg:4326")))
> cord.UTM <- spTransform(locationsC, crs(r))
> cord.UTM
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 5500 
extent      : 650979.3, 825051.9, 7280884, 7457682  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
+towgs84=0,0,0 
> TRI<-extract(r,cord.UTM,method='simple')
> TRI
   [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [37] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [73] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [109] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [145] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [181] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [217] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [253] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [289] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [325] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [361] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [397] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [433] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [469] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [505] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4500 entries ]
```

Any useful tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you projecting your locations, but then using the un-transformed point data in your extract? Should your extract expression be `extract(r, cord.UTM, method = 'simple')`?

Comment: sorry JMT2080AD was trying different things to get the script to work forgot to change this back. Have just ran the script again with the transformed locations and still getting the same issues with NAs.

Comment: you should update your post with your corrected script.

Comment: What do you see when you run `plot(r); plot(cord.UTM, add = T)`? Do the points plot on the raster in areas where there are values?

Comment: When I make the plot I can see that my location points do not relay over the raster with values.

Comment: So that is why you are getting `NA` values. The points do not intersect your raster. A couple of things could be happening: are you still having projection issues with your points? Is your raster properly projected? I noticed that you have negative extent values in your raster. Is the raster reading into R with the correct orientation (*sometimes* R's raster lib will flip rasters, confirm the orientation in QGIS)? To get an idea which is projecting correctly and which is not, view the data using `mapview` in R to see your map on a basemap. Which dataset looks incorrectly projected?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same trouble with this issue and I was very focused on the raster being the problem.  After @JMT2080AD comment, I plotted and realized my points were not lining up with my raster.  So I changed the way I did set up my points:
please note "sites" and "stacked" are my points and rasterStack that I had previously imported

```
coordinates(sites) <- ~Longitude + Latitude

crs(sites) <- crs(stacked)

values <- extract(stacked, sites)
```

That immediately fixed the problem so maybe that will help someone else as well that is running into a similar problem in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does the script below give the expected results? It's hard to know without reviewing the data you have. I am using the raster's projection to re-project your coordinates.

I am also concerned with this expression:

```
CRS("+proj=utm")
```

You are not defining what UTM you want. I don't think there is a "UTM", it's "UTM Zone 10 North", or something like that. See http://spatialreference.org/ for more info. If you aren't sure try this site: http://projfinder.com/ You can put the map on where the data is supposed to be, enter a coordinate pair, and it'll tell you what the best fit projection is for those coordinates.

```
## set the working directory                                                         
##

setwd("~/Masters/Research Project/R Scripts/Focal_Raster")

## attach packages to use                                                           
##

library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

## import the raster and the csv file that will be used in the habitat 
## location      ##
## extraction                                                                       

r <- raster("bear_12zero2.tif")
plot(r, main = "Bear Density")

hist(r[])
head(r[],200)

locations<-read.csv("locations.csv")
plot(locations$X,locations$Y, main="BearID")

## first need to assign a coordinate reference system to the csv file of
## locations that we want to extract                                                 

locationsC <- SpatialPoints(cbind(locations$X, locations$Y), 
                            proj4string=CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
cord.UTM <- spTransform(locationsC, crs(r))

## Now we just need to extract the raster values from these locations                
##
TRI <- extract(r, cord.UTM, method='simple')

## need to write CSV file to join to the master datasheet with all varibles 
## in       ##

write.csv(TRI,'beardensity.csv')
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestions using "+init=epsg:32633" rather than "+proj=utm" as this is the projection for my area I am looking at, but am still getting the NAs resulting from when I extract the values

Comment: @kate can you post the max and min of your coordinates from the csv?

Comment: These are the ones from the transformed CSV                                                           > cord.UTM
class       : SpatialPoints 
features    : 5500 
extent      : 650979.3, 825051.9, 7280884, 7457682  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

Comment: from the un-transformed csv as follows

Comment: X max = 22.38, min= 18.37; Y max= 67.08, min= 65.61

Comment: @kate Ok, so your location data is *not* in UTM 33 N. It's probably in WGS84. Your Y min = 65.61 and your Y max = 67.08. That is an area not covered by your raster's extent. I am adjusting my answer accordingly. You should check out the references I linked.

Comment: thank you have tried this out and edited the original script also added my results if this help to see where I have gone wrong more clearly