# How to extract values from stacked raster layers(asc format) to occurence(csv) data?

Tags: r, geospatial, data-analysis, raster, spatial

```
#Loading climate data
bio6 <- raster("bio_06.asc")
bio5 <- raster("bio_05.asc")
predictors <- stack(bio5, bio6) predictors`

#Loading occurrence data which is in long and lat
occ <- read.csv("presence_locations.csv")[,-1]
```

Now when I try to extract values to the occ coordinates, I get the following error.

```
`presvals <- extract(predictors, occ)
```

```
Error in extract(predictors, occ) : 
  object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

After researching a lot I didn't get the info what I need, most of the articles suggest to convert into csv format which I don't need.
[The link I tried which doesn't give me any idea(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403555/raster-subset-error-in-r-error-object-of-type-s4-is-not-subsettable)

Here's the predictors.

```
> predictors
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 9605, 7866, 76024090, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.0001297718, 0.0001297718  (x, y)
extent     : 35.5506, 36.65584, 35.58337, 37.13761  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : bio_05, bio_06
```

Here's the occurence data

```
> occ
Longitude Latitude
1    35.16556 36.25056
2    36.01378 36.55494
3    36.26056 36.97625
```

I also tried with background point. It's extracting NA values
[NAs returned when extracting values from a raster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973986/nas-returned-when-extracting-values-from-a-raster)

```
# background data
backg <- randomPoints(predictors, 1000)
absvals <- extract(predictors, backg)
> absvals
        bio_05 bio_06
   [1,]     NA     NA
   [2,]     NA     NA
```

**I would really appreciate if anyone show me how to fix this error.
**

Comment: When asking an R question, please always include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*, just like in the R help files. That is, create some data with code or use data that ships with R.

Comment: Thanks. With worldclim data it's working fine but here i'm using raw data layers that were extracted in Arcgis in .asc format and the file size is huge. Though I sorted out the problem eventually using (raster : : extract) instead of 'extract).

Comment: It is highly unlikely that explains it. Using "asc" files is a bad idea. Extracted from what? Can't you use the same data. If not, you can use GeoTIFF instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since your example is not reproducible, I just downloaded some random WorldClim historical climate data (c.f. [here](https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html)). Also, I hope you do not mind using {terra} instead of {raster}:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.49

# get data
file <- "wc2.1_10m_bio.zip"
download.file("https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/climate/worldclim/2_1/base/wc2.1_10m_bio.zip", destfile = file) 
unzip(file)

# adjust extension when working with asc files
files <- list.files(pattern = "tif$", full.names = TRUE)[15:16]
files
#> [1] "./wc2.1_10m_bio_5.tif" "./wc2.1_10m_bio_6.tif"

# load raster data
r <- rast(files)
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1080, 2160, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> sources     : wc2.1_10m_bio_5.tif  
#>               wc2.1_10m_bio_6.tif  
#> names       : wc2.1_10m_bio_5, wc2.1_10m_bio_6 
#> min values  :       -29.68600,       -72.50025 
#> max values  :        48.08275,        26.30000

# create vector data
p <- data.frame("lon" = c(35.16556, 36.01378, 36.26056),
                "lat" = c(36.25056, 36.55494, 36.97625)) |> vect(crs = "epsg:4326")
p
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : points 
#>  dimensions  : 3, 0  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : 35.16556, 36.26056, 36.25056, 36.97625  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)

# extract values from r by p
result <- extract(r, p)
result
#>   ID wc2.1_10m_bio_5 wc2.1_10m_bio_6
#> 1  1              NA              NA
#> 2  2        31.14160         6.70880
#> 3  3        31.52525         3.71825

# export extracted values to disk in csv format
write.csv(result, "result.csv")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This answer is not reproducible

Comment: Guess I should form a habit and make consequently use of `download.file()` instead of just providing URLs for manual download...

Comment: I was wondering if you could extract without any NA values. I tried with background points but all extracted values are NA which isn't suitable for any ML algo.

Comment: @dimfalk: sorry, it *is* reproducible, but it still requires a download, and that is only justified if the question is about an issue related to a particular file; to avoid the need for a good Internet connection; disk space; the risk of  "bad files", and the URL may disappear at any time in the future. You could create similar data with `rast()` instead; then your answer should be more useful and valid for a long time to come.

Comment: @perth: The `NA` values resulting from your first point is expected behaviour since the point is located in the Mediterranean Sea whereas the WorldClim dataset used is limited to land surfaces, as far as I remember. There are simply no values to extract from this raster data at that specific location. If all your values are `NA`, better check if the reference system of your points is specified correctly.

Comment: @RobertHijmans: Ok, I get your point. To demonstrate how `extract()` works, e.g. the `elev` dataset would have been sufficient. Guess I just thought to recognize the dataset used by OP, so I went for his specific use case. Will try to restrain myself regarding external data in the future... ;-)

Comment: Yes, and I think that it is more helpful (at least in the long run) to show how you can generalize a problem with example data. With many of these R problems, the art that needs to be learned seems to be the ability to isolate the problem and then look up an example in the help files. At that point, it generally is much easier to go back to the specific case and fix it. The more general the question and answer, the more useful they are for others who are looking for help. We are essentially writing a manual here.

Answer (score 2):

Example data `from terra::predict`

```
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
names(logo) <- c("red", "green", "blue")
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)
```

Extract with a 2-column matrix

```
e <- extract(logo, p)
head(e)
#  red green blue
#1 194   205  237
#2 147   161  208
#3 142   156  203
#4 221   228  254
#5 162   173  229
#6 115   129  174
```

Extract with a SpatVector

```
v <- vect(p, crs="+proj=longlat")
v
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 20, 0  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 4, 95, 7, 73  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

ve <- extract(logo, v)
head(ve)
#  ID red green blue
#1  1 194   205  237
#2  2 147   161  208
#3  3 142   156  203
#4  4 221   228  254
#5  5 162   173  229
#6  6 115   129  174
```